# Is there a better way to "Cast" one list of objects to another?

Tags: c#, list, casting, .net-3.5

I am trying to find out if there is a better way to do the attached code.  I have an List of object Device (Devices), this object inherits from another Object DeviceBase.  I have a list of DeviceBase (personInfo.devices) that I want to "Cast" into List Devices.

I am limited to .net 3.5 for this as well.

```
if (personInfo != null)
            {
                if (personInfo.devices.Count != 0)
                {
                    Devices = new List<Device>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < personInfo.devices.Count; i++)                                      //Look for a better way
                    {
                        Devices.Add((Device)personInfo.devices[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
```

My goal is to use additional methods in Devices, that DeviceBase will not have (as it is solely to Deserialize JSON).

I just feel there is a better way. While the attached is short, I am certain it can be shorter.

Comment: [Enumerable.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

```
Devices = personInfo.devices.Cast<Device>().ToList();
```